# Add suffix to an input data at the time of insert. Is this possible? (mySQL / php)

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I need to add the letter "v" as a suffix to the end of the reg data every time I insert a new record in mySQL.

Here is my insert script. Is it possible to place the letter "v" to the reg data when the client submits this PHP action to insert?

```
<?
$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add ( 
connect_date, 
reg, 
first_name, 
last_name)

VALUES

('$_POST[connect_date]', 
'$_POST[reg]', 
'$_POST[first_name]', 
'$_POST[last_name]')";

$result = mysql_query($order);

if ($result) {

$reg =      $_REQUEST['reg'] ;
$first_name =   $_REQUEST['first_name'];

header("location: reg_add_success.php?reg=" . urlencode($reg) . "&first_name=" . urlencode($first_name));
}
else {
header("location: reg_add_fail.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you to all for your feedback.  Very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$order = "INSERT INTO reg_add ( 
connect_date, 
reg, 
first_name, 
last_name)

VALUES

('$_POST[connect_date]', 
'{$_POST[reg]}v', 
'$_POST[first_name]', 
'$_POST[last_name]')";
```

Comment: yes, this is technically the correct answer, but follow the link in my answer to see how easy it is for someone to literally destroy your database, if you give them this access!

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing is INCREDIBLY dangerous. You're basically offering a malicious user everything they need to perform a sql injection.

Collect your values, validate that they don't contain any malicious code, and then perform your insert (having added whatever suffixes you wanted)!!

Seriously... this is a disaster guaranteed to happen.

Check this out:
http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

First, just append 'v' to the string.

Second,
You should NOT be using plain mysql library. You NEED TO be using mysqli (MySQL improved) library and be using prepared statements.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Otherwise your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection

Comment: Not just mysqli, you can use PDO too.

Comment: right, and at the very VERY least you need to make sure that the value doesn't contain "select | delete | update | drop | insert | alter"

Comment: That's actually not worth your time. Just use PDO/Mysqli. 

Even if you blocked the keywords I can still do or 1=1, etc...]

Answer (score 0):

Of cource you can. Just add `$_POST[reg] .= 'v';` before `$order = "...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$reg = stripslashes($_POST['reg']);
$reg = sprintf("%s%s",$reg,'v');

'".mysql_real_escape_string($reg)."',
```

Every VALUE has to has mysql_real_escape_string() function during making INSERT into MySQL.